# Programmatically set invocation property in mule

Tags: mule, invocation

I'm trying to set an invocation property in Mule 3.3.1 to be used in a "Choice" flow control. My flow has a transformer (extending the AbstractTransformer) and in it I'd like to set an invocation property based on certain logic. I can set it in the .mflow file:

```
 <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Set Invocation Variable">
    <add-message-property key="someKey" value="someValue"/>
 </message-properties-transformer>
```

However, I'm not sure how I would do this programmatically in my transformer. 
My ultimate goal is to dynamically pass the operation field in a soap client based on the mule message. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend AbstractMessageTransformer and use message.setInvocationProperty:

```
public class MyTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
        message.setInvocationProperty("someKey", "someValue");
        return message;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Seba, that worked. Before I've implemented MessageProcessor, which requires to override the process method and that did not work.